# Other monitors go black when switch one monitor to fullscreen with DXGI

Tags: c++, fullscreen, direct3d, dxgi

When I switch one of my monitor to fullscreen mode, sometimes the other monitors just become black and won't show anything. Did I do something wrong or it is just some bug?

I created a window, and then created a swapchain binded to that window. And I called the swapchain's SetFullScreenState with first parameter true, and second parameter the IDXGIOutput object of the monitor I wanted to switch fullscreen. Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes all the other monitors are lost (with only the fullscreened one showing things).

My graphics card is Radeon HD6750, and driver version is 12.3.

---

I found the MulitMon10 sample has the same problem, while some games don't. Or do Skyrim and The Tales of Monkey Island use D3D or OpenGL...?

Answer (score 0):

This question is two years old. I just came across it. 
I had a similar issue with DX11, sometimes happening in debug version, systematicaly in release version.
In my paradigm, the primary monitor hosts a console and an optional 'press buttons' GUI. The secondary monitor (one among available ones) is the fullscreen application window where 2D professional images are displayed and GPU transformed using 1D and 3D lookup tables.

Having the primary monitor going blank was a show stopper. All needed dialogs are childs of the console window (thus, opening on the primary monitor). The secondary monitor is a motion picture digital projector .... enough 'blabla'.

So, my solution was to create the swapchain in windowed mode while the targeted window was already in fullscreen mode.

Do not ask me why. It works for me. Here is a bit more:

First, my display window is set to fill the entire monitor surface ( no border, no everything).

Second, I create the swapchain for this window with “windowed = true”.

In facts, even if it looks fullscreen, it is windowed. With no border, it works the same as far as displaying/rendering 2D images is concerned. Feeding directly the backbuffer works too.

Then, and only then, you can switch the backbuffer to real administrative fullscreen. Since this operation is extremely brutal for the eyes, I tend to only do it when absolutely necessary. In effects, Win7 will reset the entire desktop (thus, all monitors, all windows) and create multiple light flashes.

When going real fullscreen after the backbuffer is created, I never experienced the desagrement of being stuck in the midle of a desktop reset (back to the original question).

To be complete, there is a difference between ‘Windowed fullscreen’ and ‘Real fullscreen’. Something you may use.

- Windowed fullscreen: other windows/dialogs will overlap your 2D creation.
- Real fullscreen: other windows/dialog should stay underneath (not visible, but there).

Toggling between the two modes upon need would be nice, except the desktop reset stress is an heavy penalty to live with.